# I thought “jalopitated” was a word?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I remember a word which means to have two things unlevel or off-kilter. I could have sworn the word was *jalopitated*.

I’m aware of the word *jalopy*, but this does not satify the requirements of being unlevel.

Does anyone know what word I am thinking of?

Comment: Sorry I should of written the more accepted term coulda

Comment: I'm confident that some writer at some time has used the word -- it's a clever combo of "jalopy" and "dilapidated", and would be at least partially understood by most native English readers/listeners.  The sort of term that the slightly off-kilter Krebsish sidekick in a comedy might use.

Comment: My car is definitely jalopidated. I shall be remembering this word for a long time.

Comment: From Jordan David, [_The Elf Directive – Book Seven of the Magi Charter_](https://books.google.com/books?id=b8JHDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT370&dq=%22jalopitated%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR2IX56-_YAhVN9mMKHcAmDV0Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22jalopitated%22&f=false) (2017): "There were even large trees lining the walk which made for approaching it difficult for the law units and the **jalopitated** tram car." This appears to be a self-published book, which might help explain the quoted sentence's extremely awkward syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are thinking of [**dilapidated**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dilapidated)

> (of a building or object) in a state of disrepair or ruin as a result of age or neglect.

---

It matches the "oldness" of the [jalopy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jalopy), which even includes dilapidated in its definition.

> An old car in a dilapidated condition.

Something that is dilapidated will generally look, as ou describe, "off kilter".

Comment: "Jalopitated" may be an new eggcorn